# Is it necessary to have (non-)localized resources in the same folder?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, localization, resources

When I don't put localized resources (Resources.***culture***.resx) in the same folder as neutral resources (i.e. non-localized - *Resources.resx*), and set current UI culture (*Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = XYZ culture)* **ResourceManager** cannot find required localized resources and uses default neutral resources for that culture.

Why is this necessary? I can't even move neutral resources to a different folder than **Properties**, because that resources won't even get loaded at startup.